# How to separate egg yolk from whites?

Tags: food, kitchen, eggs

While being careful, using your fingers etc. doesn't feel like a hack, is there any complete unique way of separating egg yolk from whites?

I originally had a real hard time trying to break open the egg at one edge and carefully ensure that only the whites fall out, this failed almost 50% of the time and I wasn't sure I was getting all the whites.

What other methods can be effective in achieving this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## The Empty-Water-Bottle Method

1. Squeeze a washed empty water bottle.
2. Place the opening of the bottle over an egg yolk, still squeezing,
   and slowly let go of your squeeze.

The yolk should get sucked right up.

In case you don't use water bottles or don't have any laying around, there are commercial suction separators like [Pluck](https://www.quirky.com/shop/426-pluck-egg-separator#.) and [Yolkr](http://www.yolkr.com/).

[image]

---

## The Hand-Strainer Method:

1. Wash your hands.
2. Crack the egg over your palm.
3. Let the egg whites drip through the spaces between your fingers until all that is left is the yolk in your hand.

[image]

---

## Buy a [Commercial Egg-Yolk Separator:](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A2KD8NY)

If you are making egg whites regularly, it might be worthwhile to buy a separator. They are inexpensive and don't require you to keep empty water bottles around or dirty your hands.

[image]

Comment: Just bought pluck! Great stocking filler etc for cooking mad wife/gf/daughter/son etc!

Answer (score 8):

I use the eggshell. Tip the yolk between the shell halves a few times (over a bowl). The albumen ends up in the bowl and the yolk in the shell.

Answer (score 7):

One good hack that I have learnt and used is to use an empty bottle.

After breaking the entire egg contents on to a bowl, press the bottle so there is air let out.  Then place the mouth of the bottle on the yellow and release the pressure.

The yellow gets sucked into the bottle leaving the white alone.

Answer (score 0):

I thought this was one of the two main uses of an eggcup! :-)

- Break the egg onto a saucer.
- Put the eggcup over the yolk.
- Pour the white off into a cup.

If a bit of white is still attached to the yolk, just cut it off using the eggcup.

Answer (score -1):

Or just buy one of these machines, hahah -> [commercial egg breaker with yolk/white separator](https://egg-breakers.com/products/egg-breakers/). That is, assuming you will be breaking A LOT of eggs :)

Comment: Using a commercial separator has already been given as an answer.